# Проверка на существование элемента массива

Tags: java, android

Как проверить, существует элемент массива или нет?

Пробовал `if (MASSIVE[1].equals(null))`, но не получилось.

Comment: `if (MASSIVE.length > 1 && MASSIVE[1] != null)`. И, кстати, почему вопрос про `split` был удалён? Решение уже нашлось?

Comment: Нет решение не нашлось, но нашлась догадся, split не создал переменную:(

Comment: Хм, всеравно вылет, 08-07 17:56:02.675    5354-5354/ux.uchat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
            at ux.uchat.AccountVoider.StartLoad(AccountVoider.java:60)

Comment: `split` работает несколько своеобразно, и для указанной в том вопросе  строке возвращал массив длины 2. Естественно, `IdNameTypePrefix[2]` приводило к появлению исключения. Я хотел было добавить ответом свою версию `split` в тот вопрос, но не успел.

Comment: Нужен полный пример, приводящий к указанному исключению `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Тоесть хотели предложить свою версию split, очень жду

Comment: Вот как я получаю эту строчку String[] IdNameTypePrefix="50<br>tortik tortik<br><br>".split("<br>");

Comment: А дальше пробую проверить существует элемент или нет if(IdNameTypePrefix[2] == null)  ну а дальше вылет, именно на условии

Comment: Вы весьма напрасно пропустили вот эту часть в моём комментарии: `MASSIVE.length > 1`. С соответствующей проверкой длины массива исключение появляться не будет: `if (IdNameTypePrefix.length < 2 || IdNameTypePrefix[2] == null) `. Отредактированная версия `split` из моего проекта: [пример](http://goo.gl/4vahb7).

Comment: Спасибо за сервис, но заметил один недочет, Теперь третего элемента нету...

Comment: Вот пример `"50<br>tortik tortik<br><br>"`

Comment: И вот строчка у которой 3 элемент появляется

Comment: `10<br>Котляров Денис<br>TEEST<br>2`

Comment: Как так, почему не создается? а 2 элемент создается

Comment: А, простите, я понел я делаю на третий элемент Integer.parseInt и он тоже дает вылет

Comment: Как сделать чтобы он возвращал `Integer.parseInt(IdNameTypePrefix[3])`, чтоб был результат 0

Comment: А все, написал себе полезную функцию, выполняет то что и требовалось, ну если пустая строчка возвращает 0 `public static int toInt(String name){
        if(name.length() == 0)return 0;
        else Integer.parseInt(name);

        return 0;
    }`

Comment: Спасибо, напишешь ответ, отмечу как правильный и +1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для проверки того, что элемент с заданным индексом существует в массиве и не равен `null`, можно использовать такое условие:

```
if (MASSIVE.length > 1 && MASSIVE[1] != null)
```

Разбитие строки на подстроки (с учетом пустых подстрок):

```
public static String[] split(String original, String separator)
{
    ArrayList<String> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = original.indexOf(separator);
    while (index >= 0)
    {
        nodes.add(original.substring(0, index));
        original = original.substring(index + separator.length());
        index = original.indexOf(separator);
    }
    nodes.add(original);
    return nodes.toArray(new String[nodes.size()]);
}
```

[Пример на tutorialspoint.com](http://goo.gl/4vahb7).

Код хоть и не оптимален и представляет собой немного доработанную версию метода `split` для моего проекта на JDK1.2, но работает.

Доработанный метод `toInt` из комментариев:

```
public static int toInt(String name)
{
    int result = 0;
    try
    {
        result = Integer.parseInt(name);
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    return result;
}
```

[Пример на tutorialspoint.com](http://goo.gl/rMphEq).

Comment: А, спасибо не знал что parseInt реагирует на try, catch

Comment: @ДенисКотляров на здоровье. Да, это разом исключает все "плохие" варианты, в случае которых нужно возвращать `0`.